# Text property in windows form populated from a resource file

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

I need to be able to integrate the strings from a resource file with my windows forms. Is it possible, such that, when clicking on the properies of a field, the Text property can be populated with values from a resource file rather than manually writing the text?

In other words, is it possible to do this from the designer interface rather than from the designer code?

Comment: Do you mean that you add there's a dropdown with "RESOURCE_KEY"'s in the TextField's "Text" property in the Visual Studio Editor?

Comment: not sure if i am understanding you, but yes I want that I can access the resource string from visual studio interface. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- In the *Properties* window for a form set *Localizable* property to true.
- It will cause that resources will be automatically generated for localisable properties of all controls in the given form.
- Besides theses resources will be automatically applied to controls i.e. the code similar to the following will be added to designer code:  *resources.ApplyResources(this.button1, "button1");*

The main problem with this approach is that each control have many localisable properties. In other words your resx file would contain many records.